# Looking for tool to split german text into sentences

Tags: computational-linguistics, german, sentences

I want to train a german embedding and need to split text into sentences. That is not easy since "z. B." and "Dr." are not endings of a sentence. Does anybody know a tool to do that for german texts? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this here to be the best solution for my problem:
https://github.com/tsproisl/SoMaJo

I compared it to spaCy and NLTK but SoMaJo was better quality in sentence splitting the german texts.

Answer (score 2):

Just searching for `tokenizer german` I came up with [Stefanie Dipper's tokenizer for German](https://www.linguistics.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/~dipper/resources/tokenizer.html). It comes with a somewhat non-commercial license (read it before download).

Comment: It works but this question is really *sentence boundary detection* not *tokenisation*.

Comment: It is usual that a tokenizer does sentence boundary detection as well and that there is no separate tool for this task.

Answer (score 2):

**spaCy** does **[sentence boundary detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_boundary_disambiguation)** (*sentence segmentation*, *sentence breaking*).  It also supports German.

See https://spacy.io/api/doc#sents for an example:

[image]